# Giving a widget my own id or class in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin with a widget. In my jQuery code i'd like to point to that widget, so I though giving it an **HTML ID** would be nice. *(Edited, thanks for pointing out.)*

After doing some searching on the internet (and the Codex) I know that I can give ID's to the widgets in the theme, but it's not what I was looking for. This method has flaws. Changing the theme may cause errors (of course, ***I*** know it has to be changed in the *functions.php*, but it's just meh). The other thing is that my widget got a number which may change without me knowing.

So to be 100% sure it works and will work in the future, can I give my widget **my own ID**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might not understand your question exactly and what `"ID"` do you mean ( widget ID , or actual HTML div ID - which are actually one and the same.. ) but If you have read the codex , the example for how to give an ID is given there ..

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'foo_widget', // Base ID
            __('Widget Title', 'text_domain'), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }
```

Another way to do the same ( and helpul if you are talking about `HTML` elements like `divs` - you can assign a `class` )

```
function My_Widget() {  
    function My_Widget() {  
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => __('A widget that displays nothing ', 'example') );  
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'example-widget' );  
        $this->WP_Widget( 'example-widget', __('Example Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );  
    }
```

Note that a numerator will be automatically added to your widget´s ID based on how many instances were initiated like :

```
foo_widget
foo_widget-2
foo_widget-3
```

etc ...

**EDIT I** - after comments

At any rate , IMHO it is a bad idea to hard-code a fixed `ID` in a widget for the simple reason that the preference for a widget from the developer point of view is to always allow support for multiple instances . Giving an an `HTML ID` anywhere on the widget will cause validation errors AND in the case of `jQuery` - also `JS` errors for the simple cause that if a user will have 2 widgets , it will also have a duplicated ID .

In other words - It is the exact opposite of your statement in the original question.

> So to be 100% sure it works and will work in the future, can I give my
> widget my own ID

Giving a fixed hard coded ID to your widget will in fact ensure that it will **NOT** work 100% of the time.

The preference is always to target such issues with a `class` ( or with something like `div[id^="my_widget_id"]` ) and let wordpress "do it´s thing" ( by auto incrementing IDs ).

For the exact same reason  - a theme should always have the same structure in the `register sidebar()` function like so :

```
<?php $args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'unique-sidebar-id',
    'description'   => '',
        'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">', // LOOK AT THIS LINE 
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' ); ?>
```

This will permit the specific sidebar to `auto increment` the ID of the widgets in order to avoid the above mentioned problem .

From the codex :

> before_widget - HTML to place before every widget(default: '') Note: uses sprintf for variable
> substitution

All that being said, and if you are insisting of giving a hard-coded fixed ID somewhere there ( instead of a the methods described above ) you can always put that at a nested `div`or `span` INSIDE your widget´s HTML output, But I would think that if you have read attentively this answer - you will avoid it now.

Now,- since you have not included any code in your question ( which is always a bad practice here on SE ) there is little more I can do to help. If you encounter any problems targeting the widget without an ID - I suggest you to open a new question and maybe point a link at the comments here, so myself ( and others ) can help you with it ..

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my point was to avoid having to modify the theme's functions.php file. Is there no way of doing that?

Comment: I am sorry, I understood from your Original question that you are writing your own widget .

Comment: Yes, I am. But I want my widget to work with other themes and that's why I don't want to depend on a theme's function.php file. Is that bad?

Comment: @Martin Fejes - No, nothing is bad . but there are two possibilities here, either 1. I do not understand your question/problem, - or  2. you do not understand how widgets work .If you do your code correctly - the ID of the widget will be the HTML ID no matter what theme will display it . I have written tens of widgets ( Most with some kind of jQuery ) and never had a notch of problem. Maybe you should specify your problem better ( maybe some code ?? ).

Comment: Sorry this is my first widget. Maybe I misunderstood you. When I modified the construct of my widget to give it an ID, I still had to set before_widget in the theme's register_sidebar. Am I missing something? Can I change the before_widget only on my widget?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer, I had some urgent things. Thank you for you effort, now I understand. :)